# ssrs error converting data type nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssrs-2017

I passed this stored procedure into ssrs to generate a report but kept getting error converting data type nvarchar to int, while i don't even have any parameter that's nvarchar type.

```
Alter proc dbo.spPullOrderRosa1
@Subentity int,
@BegShipDate date,
@EndShipDate date,
@Store varchar(150),
@State varchar(150)
as
begin

select OpOrID as OrID, OpID, concat(OrCuFirstName,' ',OrCuLastName) as CustomerName,
b.SoName as StoreName,OpPrSKU as SKU, OpQty,StLongName as StateName,
cast(OpShipDate as date) as ShipDate, 
cast(d.DeliveryDate as date) as DeliveryDate,
e.StyName as SubEntity

from csn_order..tblOrderProduct a with (nolock)
left join csn_order..tblOrder f with (nolock) on a.OpOrID = f.OrID
left join csn_order..tblStore b with (nolock) on a.OpSoID = b.SoID
left join csn_order..tblplState c with (nolock) on f.OrCuStID = c.StID
left join csn_order..tblDeliveryDate d with (nolock) on a.OpID = d.DeliveryOpID
left join csn_order.dbo.tblSubEntity e with (nolock) on b.SoStyID = e.StyID
where (OpCancelled = 0) and (b.SoID in (select SoID from csn_order..tblStore where SoName in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Store, ','))  )) 
and (StID in (select StID from csn_order..tblplState where StLongName in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@State, ',')) )) 
and (StyID =  @Subentity) and (OpShipDate >= @BegShipDate and OpShipDate <= @EndShipDate)
```

end

Comment: What type are all your ID fields (used in joins) and OpCancelled? Any comparison of int and nvarchar value can result in such error.

Comment: Are any of your SSRS parameters multi-select? e.g. if @Subentity is a multi-select then IDs will be passed as a comma separated string varchar(max). E.g. "12, 34, 16"

Comment: Does the SP work OK from Management Studio, and is the error just happening in SSRS?

Comment: State and Store are multi-select but i used string_split for them

Comment: ID fields are all int

Comment: it worked in sql but not in SSRS

Comment: I just created an exactly same rdl file in SSRS and it worked.. there is no problem with  my sp..i wonder if it's just random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely would not write it off as just random, you don't want this popping back up when certain conditions are met. Here are a few things I'd try to narrow it down

1) You use LEFT JOINs, it can leave NULL values in fields you expect to be integers (like QTY), try wrapping them in COALESCE statements in your SELECT clause

```
SELECT COALESCE(OpQty, 0) as OpQty, ...
```

2) SSRS might be guessing the data type wrong, it might think a character field is an integer if the first few values are numbers. Figure out which field is generating the error, and perhaps cast it explicitly to NVARCHAR so SSRS won't try to use it as an integer

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(50), OpPrSKU) as SKU, ...
```

3) SSRS might have added a "TOTAL" field at the end of a DETAIL group, so it's trying to do math on a field that isn't a number. This is less likely, but possible so at least worth looking for.

But the important thing is to figure out WHICH field is generating the error so you can focus your attention on it.

EDIT: If you're using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can also explicitly set the data types returned using the EXECUTE  WITH RESULT SETS clause in your dataset in the report. A good example is http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlstudies/2016/01/14/what-is-result-sets/

Note that this has the disadvantage that if you update the stored procedure definition to include more columns, you must remember to track down and update all reports that use it. If your setting doesn't change SP definitions then it's not an issue and is the most reliable way to tell SSRS what the right types are, but for me casting the type inside the SP is more flexible in the long run and is enough for SSRS in every case I've encountered.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I don't think it's something wrong with the stored procedure - because if so, i would not be able to get it run in SSRS just with another rdl file. I created two rdl files to run the sp and i believe they are the same, at least in the SSRS (not in a code level), and one worked while the other didn't. if it is the second or third reason, then they should both work.

Comment: I'm currently comparing the two rdl file in notepad and trying to figure out if there's some default setting difference between them.

Comment: I agree that it's not a problem in the stored procedure, I think the problem is in SSRS incorrectly guessing the data type, I'm suggesting modifying the stored procedure to "trick" SSRS into guessing the correct type for all data.

Comment: but in that case, why two same rdl file would give back different result?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact mechanism, but SSRS seems to grab a sample of data when you first define a dataset and use it to estimate field types, if something changes (like new data in the table, or even just a different ordering) after you define the first RDL, the new RDL may have a better guess. Again, YMMV, but if I had the "broken" RDL still I'd try to figure out which field had caused the problem. A RDL isn't likely to "break" once it has data types set, but a new report might guess wrong again absent explicit typing.

Comment: I found out why. In the dataset that passes sp, the parameter value is not included in square brackets. it ended up showing as @subrntity instead of parameter!@subrntity.value in the html code. After I changed this, my rdl file worked!

Comment: I think you are right about the guess problem. It's just SSRS cannot really figure out what is the input, since i didnt point the parameters to any real value. So it took @subentity as nvarchar instead of $subentity.value, which is an int.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working and thanks for posting back what the problem was, it helps others (maybe even me!) in the future who come across this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my 2 cents in (Knowing this post is already over 2 years old) and I am not saying this will work for everyone. I was experiencing the same issue as OP.

I created a new rdl file and copied over all the objects.